# Android AlertDialog inflater error

Tags: android, runtime-error, layout-inflater

I'm trying to create an `AlertDialog`, but I'm getting some errors. The dialog is shown when the user click a `ListView` item.

Here is the `AlertDialog` function:

```
private void showNewNotebookDialog() {
    LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
    AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    dialogBuilder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.notebook_new, null));
    dialogBuilder.setCancelable(true);
    dialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

        }
    });
    dialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });
    AlertDialog dialog = dialogBuilder.create();
    dialog.show();
}
```

And here is the `notebook_new.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/notebook_new_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp">        
    <TextView android:text="New notebook"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"/>      
    <EditText android:id="@+id/notebook_new_edittext"
        android:hint="Enter a title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:maxLines="1"/>        
</RelativeLayout>
```

And the errors:

```
<VM does not provide monitor information>   
PhoneLayoutInflater(LayoutInflater).inflate(int, ViewGroup, boolean) line: 399  
PhoneLayoutInflater(LayoutInflater).inflate(int, ViewGroup) line: 353   
MainActivity.showNewNotebookDialog() line: 112  
MainActivity.access$0(MainActivity) line: 107   
MainActivity$1.onItemClick(AdapterView, View, int, long) line: 70   
ListView(AdapterView).performItemClick(View, int, long) line: 301   
ListView(AbsListView).performItemClick(View, int, long) line: 1283  
AbsListView$PerformClick.run() line: 3076   
AbsListView$1.run() line: 4149  
Handler.handleCallback(Message) line: 615   
ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 92 
Looper.loop() line: 137 
ActivityThread.main(String[]) line: 4921    
Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean) line: not available [native method]  
Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 511  
ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 1038 
ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 805 
NativeStart.main(String[]) line: not available [native method]
```

Comment: Could be a problem with this directive `android:maxLines="1"`? Can you remove it and try again.

Comment: Else the `android:layout_height` directive is missing with your `EditText` component. I am surprised Android Lint hasn't pick up on this.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the `android:layout_height` directive for your `EditText` component. You need something like:

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/notebook_new_edittext"
    android:hint="Enter a title"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:maxLines="1"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/notebook_new_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp">        
    <TextView android:text="New notebook"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"/>      
    <EditText android:id="@+id/notebook_new_edittext"
        android:hint="Enter a title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" <!-- you are missing this line -->
        android:maxLines="1"/>        
</RelativeLayout>
```